# How can I display both LTR and RTL language texts on the same page?

Tags: customization

My WP website is multi-lingual and I can put two different LTR language texts, e.g., English and Chinese, on the same page. But as I put English / Chinese texts together with Arabic texts in different paragraph on the same page, one of them was displayed incorrectly. The problem is the punctuation mark "." (full-stop)  at the end of the sentence was position incorrectly.

That means if I used LTR "mode" for the site, then the Arabic texts will end up with the last "." of the paragraph wrongly placed on the right hand side. However, if I used RTL "mode" for the site, then the English texts will end up with the last "." at the end of the paragraph was wrongly placed on the left hand side.

My website is using the Sixteen WP theme by InkHive, version 1.7.2. My questions are:

(1) How to solve this punctuation mark positioning problem with the Sixteen WP theme?

(2) If this can't be resolved in the Sixteen WP theme, is there other WP theme that can handle and resolve this problem, at the "field" within the "page" level.

Thank you ALL.

Francis

Comment: Sorry, this isn't my area of expertise, but if you're just typing the different language content to a page, can't you just place the punctuation where you need it yourself?

Comment: The problem is once you hit the "Enter" button, the theme atomatically re-positions your punctuation mark on the RHS if you are using the LTR "mode", irrepective of whether your language is LTR or RT writing system. Similarly, the punctuation mark will be auto-positoned on the LHS of the sentence if you are using the RTL "mode", irrepective of whether your language is LTR or RTL writing system.